# Why is python matching the wrong pattern?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
look = r'Template.11_31.Single-Volume'
pattern = r'11.31'

match = re.search(pattern,look)

print re.findall(pattern,look)

if (match is not None):
    print match.group(0)
```

Answer:

```
['11_31']
11_31
```

I want it to match `11.31` or `1131` but here it also matches `11_31`

Comment: maybe I am not answering your question, but you will like this syntax sugar: print "".join(match.group(0) if match is not None else "")

Answer (score 5):

Problem is in your regex `11.31` dot will **match any character**.

You can use this regex:

```
pattern = r'11\.?31'
```

This will match `11.31` or `1131` but not `11_31` or `11:31` since `\.` matches a literal dot and `\.?` makes dot an optional match.

**Example:**

```
>>> print re.findall(pattern, "Template.11.31.Single-Volume-1131-something")
['11.31', '1131']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pattern =r'11.31'
```

Here `.` can match anything so it will match `_` in `11_31` as well. Either escape it (`\.`) or put it in character class (`[.]`) and add more to it as when required.

Use this

```
pattern =r'11[.]?31'
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/21